# how to remove line breaks in a (.tsv) file

Tags: bash, command-line, bioinformatics

I have a large square correlation matrix file (110,000 RXC) for human transcript data in .tsv format (File name = corr_trans.tsv). When I tried to extract correlation data for a transcript (say ENST00000568709) from a matrix, I got no results, It shows a header that has this transcript, but not the main row with correlation data. When I tried the same step for some other transcripts, It gave results for the transcripts present in the top 22000 rows. After that, it is not able to read the file. As per my past knowledge/experience, this is because of a line break error and I want to know how to remove line break error in a tsv file.

I don't need any output files. I only want my whole matrix file to be read.

Thank you

Sample data (File name = corr_trans.tsv)

```
transcript_id   ENST0000000233  ENST0000000412  ENST00000001008  ENST00000001146
ENST0000000233  1   0.128095164 0.122437557 0.032729413
ENST0000000412  0.128095164 1   -0.010030176    0.07378663
ENST00000001008 0.122437557 -0.010030176    1   0.011332091
ENST00000001146 0.032729413 0.07378663  0.011332091 1
```

When I am trying to grep data for ENST0000000412 with the command

```
grep "ENST0000000233" corr_trans.tsv
```

I get output (2 rows)

```
transcript_id   ENST0000000233  ENST0000000412  ENST0000001008   ENST00000001146
ENST0000000233  1   0.128095164 0.122437557 0.032729413
```

However, when I try this for ENST00000001146

I get only one row as output and not the row with correlation data

```
transcript_id   ENST0000000233  ENST0000000412  ENST0000001008   ENST00000001146
```

In the real matrix, this error is happing after 22000 rows.

Comment: What are you talking about? "Large Matrix File"? "110,000 (RxC)"? "a correlation data for a transcript"? "after some lines"? "This error"? "transcripts which are in the top 10%-20%"? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question and rephrase it in computational terms. I don't know what your subject domain is, but "_I am trying to grep a correlation data for a transcript_" means nothing to me at all. Similarly, "_This error doesn't come in the transcripts which are in the top 10%-20%._" also means nothing to me. An example data file (emphatically not the full data set!) and the expected result for that data set would be extremely helpful

Comment: Oh, I've found a question in the title, "_how to remove line breaks in a (.tsv) file_". If this is what you want then focus on this. Show us a sample tsv file, highlight the issue, and show us what you want as output.

Comment: Priya thank you for editing your question. I still don't understand any of it except that you have a data file containing unexpected line breaks and you want it fixed. You need to show us the relevant part of the broken data file or a similarly broken example, and you need to tell us - or better still show us - how you want this data file to look after it's been fixed. Without this information your question is impossible to answer

Comment: without even downloading your sample data (i.e. just searching within the browser) I can see that you have mismatching data.  On the transcript_id line, you have `ENST00000001146` (15 characters) but on the data line, you have `ENST0000001146` (14 characters).  Probably an extra `0` got into the transcript_id line somehow.

Comment: @cas: Sorry, please ignore this extra 0, I typed this example for the question (it is a typological error). There is no such issue in the real matrix

Comment: @Priya Please update your question with the correct example data. If someone is to help you, the would use the data in the question.

Comment: can you add the output of `awk 'NR > 21995 && NR < 22005' corr_trans.tsv | cat -nvet` to your question?   That should show the problematic line and a few lines around it, with line-numbers and non-printing chars.

Comment: I don't see how this issue can be resolved programmatically. If the data set has been corrupted you're going to need to regenerate it, or get a clean copy from its source